# "unnatural" filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

What would be an example of a simple/useful stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ for $T=\mathbb{N}$ or $T=\mathbb{R}$ where it is useful to consider a filtration different from the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}^X_t:=\sigma\{X_s :s\le t\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you were looking for, but perhaps still interesting. Let $T = \mathbb{R}^+$, take $X$ to be Brownian motion. Then the natural filtration is not right-continuous. So instead, it's often preferred to augment the filtration to be right-continuous.

To see that the natural filtration is not right-continuous: [Proving that the natural filtration of Brownian motion (not augmented) is not right-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216322/proving-that-the-natural-filtration-of-brownian-motion-not-augmented-is-not-ri)

Comment: This was still interesting regarding my question but I didn't understand in the comment of the link why "An event $∈\mathcal{F}_$ has the property that if $∈$ and if $′∈Ω$ is such that $′()=()$ for all $∈[0,]$ then $′∈$ as well"